# Eclipse: keyboard shortcut to move tabs around?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to setup an Eclipse keyboard shortcut which will split the current editor vertically and put the current tab on one side? For example, turning this:

[before http://img.skitch.com/20100118-1n5xeuywunri6b91nfjpgdxxne.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100118-1n5xeuywunri6b91nfjpgdxxne.png)

Into:

[after http://img.skitch.com/20100118-t2c7g3nctx3w8bth4hq1rpqp9k.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100118-t2c7g3nctx3w8bth4hq1rpqp9k.png)

Comment: Title is a bit misleading. I came here as looking for a shortcut to move tabs around (i.e. reorder them), not split editors. And since this page is pretty high up on the Google list, a lot of people in my situation are bound to come, or have come by.

Comment: Ah… Sorry :\ If you ask a similar question, I could give you some upvotes and create a link from this question.

Comment: _<continued from the comment above since I could not edit after 5 minutes>_
I may ask a question soon, but there's no need for linking and upvoting since the community is large enough. I think it would be best if you edited the title to better reflect the nature of the question (maybe something including both "move" and "split", or similar). This way those who want to do the same as you can easily find the question and those like me can skip it.

Comment: Since the above comments don't seem to have got through... I'll bring it up again, please change the title for your question.  "Eclipse: keyboard shortcut to move tabs around?" sounds like it is about reordering the tabs and not about how to create splits.  For others that erroneously found themselves here, here is a link to the question that I'm looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276852/how-to-move-eclipse-tabs-with-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Not directly with eclipse (3.4 or 3.5)

The closest plugin I have found which *might* enable what you are looking for is the **[Split file Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Implement_Split_File_Editor_Functionality_for_the_Eclipse_IDE)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

> Usage: Open a file in Eclipse, then select Window -> New Split Editor from the main menu to open a split editor of the file.

(not *exactly* what you want but:)

> Split editor opens in a new tab as opposed to appearing within the existing tab

(so while there may be 2 instances of the same file editor, you still have a situation with one file on one side, and the other files on the other tab group)

Comment: Using <kbd>: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

Comment: kbd: use with moderation ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive