# How to move Eclipse tabs with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to move my tabs in Eclipse like this :

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

But using a keyboard shortcut, 'cause is very annoying doing this with the mouse everytime just to reorder the tabs.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a shortcut. Tabs are shown in the order you open them. But you can switch the tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>. Or select one tab in the list of opened tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: but I would like to reorder them by keyboard.

Comment: i prefer to go with Ctrl+ Pageup and Pagedown but want one eclipse plugin which can be use same with tab + Ctrl like chrome and other browser. If somebody have any info for plug-in please share